# Laravel 5.6 Login credentials multiple tables

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have two different tables for users credentials: "users" and "contacts". In contacts I have stored users emails, phone and other contacts informations. I want to use the emails in contacts table for the login and authentication methods in Laravel but I don't know how to setup the User and Contacts models or something else that I need. Any idea how can I use contacts and users tables for the login in the application? I'm new in Laravel, any help is appreciated, thank you!

Below a basic tables structure in mysql db:

**users**: id | username |  password

**contacts**: email | phone | other | user_id

Comment: This is a very bad practice of setting up a database. What is the difference between a user and a contact? Do contact and a user have these attributes: firstname, lastname, email, phone? If answer is YES, then they should all be in the same table!

Comment: Hi @lewis4u, yes it's strange but we've got also users (minors) that don't have an email or phone. Anyway thank you for you comment.

Comment: Add the `phone` column to `users` table. All auth should be in a single table. Authentication is too complicated to spread it out liberally. [This guide](https://medium.com/@jagadeshanh/laravel-5-4-login-with-email-or-phone-cac9a3855cda) inspired the solution I built for a more complex but similar issue. Think of password resets, email and phone changes, phone removal, security logs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LoginController`, you can overwrite the `attemptLogin` method as follow:

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request) {
    $contact = Contact::where('email', $email)->first();

    if (Auth::attempt(['id' => $contact->user_id, 'password' => $password])) {

        // Authentication passed...
    }
}
```

OR

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request) {
    $user = User::whereHas('contacts', function($query){
        $query->where('email', $email);
    });

    if (Auth::login($user)) {

        // Authentication passed...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need a custom controller for what you suggested? Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting `attemptLogin()`, which somehow does not work out for me. I prefer overwriting `credentials()`, which ensures that all auth which is "correctly" implemented will use the "correct" values.

How this could look like:

```
/**
 * Get authorization credentials from request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    // username is set in LoginController to email
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $contact = Contact::where($this->username(), $credentials[$this->username()])->first();

    // if we've not found a contact, we fallback to default
    if (! $contact) {
        return $credentials;
    }

    // else we set user_id and password  as credential params
    return array_merge($request->only('password'), [
        'user_id' => $contact->user_id,
    ]);
}
```